# Creating a new folder with parameter names without overwriting the existing results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running multiple consoles with parameters and saved my model and results in a folder with the naming convention as below:

**mlp_model_1**

At times I just rerun the results for same conditions, but I need to save the results as a different name. So I understand I have to check for existing directory  using `os.path.exists(path)`, but how do I name a new folder for the same parameters.

Currently, I have the two functions for it which overwrites the folder with same name.

```
def check_dir(path, else_create=False):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        shutil.rmtree(path)
        print('Delete dir')
    if else_create:
        os.makedirs(path)

def create_dir(path, else_create=False):
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        print('Create new')
        os.makedirs(path)
```

Comment: Just to improve your code a little, check out `os.path.makedirs()` and use `if not os.path.isdir(path):` instead of `if os.path.isdir(path) == 0:`. Same for `if else_create:`, that'll work by itself.

Comment: @DanielLenz Sorry, I could not get what you have mentioned here.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to make it clearer, will hopefully get approved soon.

Comment: @DanielLenz Implemented your suggested changes, It still deletes the first folder it created and overwrites results.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was ambigious; my suggestions didn't change anything the code _does_, it just makes it cleaner and more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do what operating systems do when you duplicate a file - add a number after it?

```
def create_dir(path, else_create=False):
    if(os.path.isdir(path) is False):
        print('Creating new directory: New_model')
        call(["mkdir", path])
    else:
        i = 2
        while(os.path.isdir(path + str(i))):
            i += 1
        print('Creating a new directory: New_model')
        call(["mkdir", path + str(i)])
```

This piggybacks off of the method you wrote: First, it checks if the folder already exists. If not, it creates the directory. That's what you already had. I've added code for when the folder *does* already exist: it starts a number, starting at `2`, and appends it to the folder name. If that exists, it increments the number again, and so on, until the folder does not exist, and thus can be created.

So you would end up with a set of folders like the following:

```
mlp_lstm_model
mlp_lstm_model2
mlp_lstm_model3
...
```

Comment: It just creates with folder name '2' when I use the above code.  In my code, I have defined the variables as the following to have the convention:                           
`tag = 'mlp_lstm'+'_lstm_size_'+str(lstm_dim)+'_batch_size_'+str(batch_size) 
  model_path = '../saved_models/'+tag+'_model/' 
 create_dir('../saved_models/')`